# Sluggish performance on Lenovo U410... Display driver issue?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, intel-graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo U410 laptop. This system runs Windows 8 very well, it is only a few months old, but Ubuntu runs sluggish as heck (Chrome takes about 15s to open... instant open in Windows).

On my desktop, I had to get Nvidia drivers going before I saw ok performance. On this laptop, my video card is registered as Unknown.

This laptop has a Hybrid card A Nvidia 610M + Intel HD 4000 graphics. I've tried to read up on what driver to install, but I am getting conflicting reports. And I don't want to brick the install like I did on my desktop (wrong driver = no desktop at all). Should I be looking at the Intel driver for the 4000 graphics or the Nvidia Driver for the 610M?

Comment: Hi Neil, please read the link provided which should solve your "Unknown" issue, the performance for Intel and Nvidia and other issues you might have using a Hybrid.